# SQL Server CSV per row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have Data Like:

```
StudentID | Course
1         | .NET
1         | SQL Server
1         | Ajax
2         | Java
2         | JSP
2         | Struts
```

I want the query to get the Output data Like the following.

```
StudentID | Course
    1     | .NET, SQL Server, Ajax
    2     | Java, JSP, Struts
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2005+, the easiest method is the to use the FOR XML trick:

```
SELECT StudentID, STUFF((SELECT ',' + Course
                         FROM table t1
                         WHERE t1.StudentID = t.StudentID
                         FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM table t
```

Comment: @Hemanth: Please accept this as an answer, if it answered your question

Comment: @Hemanth & @Stuart Ainsworth, `FOR XML PATH` is the way to go, however this answer does not do it in the best manner.  This answer will fail to work properly if the data to concatenate contains some common characters like `>`, `<`, `&`.  see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7284932/65223 for a better `FOR XML PATH` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLServer2000+ you can use following

```
create table tbl (StudentID int, course varchar(10))

insert into tbl values (1,'.NET'),(1, 'SQL Server'), (1,  'Ajax'),(2,'Java'),(2,'JSP'),(2,'Struts')

GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetCourses(@id INTEGER)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Result = ''
SELECT @Result = @Result +  [course] + ' ' FROM tbl WHERE StudentID = @id
RETURN RTRIM(@Result)
END
GO

SELECT DISTINCT StudentID, dbo.GetCourses(StudentID) FROM tbl
GO

drop table tbl
drop function  dbo.GetCourses
```

Comment: @Igor your answer returns the correct result. But it is not pretty. You can improve your function in several ways also your 'select distinct' is calling your function way to many times.

Comment: @Hemanth You are wellcome. But if an answer was helpfull you need to vote it up, and accept the best answer.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk I deleted extra CAST from the function, but I don't see how can I improve it any more. About "'select distinct' is calling your function way to many times" you also cannot do anything about it (by the way Compute scalar takes 0% of actual execution plan).

Comment: @Igor you are running the function for each element in course which is not nessasary. Consider this: SELECT StudentID, dbo.GetCourses(StudentID) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT StudentID FROM tbl) a

Comment: @t-clausen.dk I understand what you meen. Your SELECT is more logical but the optimizer treat my and your variants as equal. They both take 50 % of actual and estimated execution plans. I have Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (Intel X86)   Jun 17 2011 00:57:23   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition with Advanced Services on Windows NT 6.1 <X86> (Build 7600: ).